# Where can I use drawInRect for strings?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uikit

I'm having some trouble tracking down the exact usage of drawInRect; I know the syntax, but is it only available inside a UIView or its subclass? What exactly is the "context" required, and how to I create or get it?

Comment: same or related problem is i got is
[this will help you][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477509/how-to-use-nsstring-drawinrect-to-centre-text

Comment: i'm looking for a broader sense of usage; i already know the syntax. i'm asking *where* it can be placed, i.e. what types of views

Comment: and more specifically, what is referred to as the "context" for a method like drawInRect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context is like the canvas for core graphics drawing. You can get the context from any UIView by calling `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()` within `drawRect:`. You can also create your own context anywhere, from which you can create a UIImage or save to a file, etc.

Hope this helps!

Comment: how does one "create" a canvas? I'm having a difficult time finding documentation about this specifically.

Comment: Here's a good reference page: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_context/dq_context.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH203-TPXREF101