# String Alignment in NSFont / NSView

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsview, nsfont

He, when I draw Text into my view like this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *textAttrib = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[textAttrib setObject:[NSFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Light" size:15] forKey:NSFontAttributeName];
[textAttrib setObject:[NSColor grayColor] forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
[mouseString drawAtPoint:textPoint withAttributes:textAttrib];
```

how can I change the alignment of the text? I just need simple left/right alignment and can't find any info about that, only in textfields. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such concept of alignment with the `[NSString drawAtPoint:withAttributes:]` method, and this makes sense if you think about it.  Alignment is concept of how a string appears relative to the content of a control (classically an `NSTextField`).

You could, however, try `[NSString drawInRect:withAttributes:]` where that concept does exist.  See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477509/how-to-use-nsstring-drawinrect-to-centre-text).

**UPDATE**: This question isn't complete without the (now deleted) answer given by @justin, which shows *how* to set the text alignment in an `NSAttributedString`.  Both are answers are correct, but neither is complete.

Comment: @justin Please undelete your answer as it shows the mechanics involved in setting the alignment.

Comment: tried justins answer: runs, but NSLeftTextAlignment or NSRightTextAlignment makes no difference.

Comment: @fw2601 and did try it *combined* with my answer?

Comment: Have you thought about what alignment means when just a point, rather than a rect, is specified however? The method doesn't know how much space it's got to work with when just a point is specified, but it does when a rect is used.

Comment: I don't understand that. By default its left-aligned, text is drawn from the point I specify to the right. What's the conceptual difference to right-alignment?

Comment: The alignment isn't honoured when using `drawAtPoint:`.  Rather you are going to have to tell the rect within which to draw (using `drawInRect:`) and then alignment will be honoured. I know this complicates your implementation, but it's the only way to get what you want.

Comment: Ok, thank you. That makes things complicated. And it's so easy in javascript/HTML5...

Answer (score 1):

You are missing an attribute: NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, which is a NSParagraphStyle attribute. If you create a NSParagraphStyle object, you could set this property:

```
@property(readonly) NSTextAlignment alignment;  // readwrite for NSMutableParagraphStyle
```

In your case you should set it to NSTextAlignmentLeft, or NSTextAlignmentRight.

**Example**:

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle* style=[[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc]init];
style.alignment= NSTextAlignmentLeft;
[textAttrib setObject: style forKey: NSParagraphStyleAttributeName];
```