# How to create a centre align Nsstring

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have NSString strings that represent Product name Quantity Price 
I need to align columns of these values like this

```
Productname         Qty    Price
PLAIN T-SHIRT         5    50.00 
BLACK DENIM           1    29.99 
BLUE DENIM            3    29.99
STRIPED DRESS         1    49.99
BLACK BOOTS           2    35.99
```

How ever I try using

```
+(NSString *) get_TOT:(NSString *)tot_STR : (int) length_range
{
   NSString *tmp_TT;
   NSUInteger length = tot_STR.length;
   NSRange range;
    tmp_TT = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"                                 %d    %f",Qty,pricc];
    if (length <= 33)
    {
        range = NSMakeRange(33-length, length);
        tmp_TT = [tmp_TT stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:tot_STR];
    }
    else
    {
        tmp_TT = [tmp_TT substringToIndex:33];
    }      
return tmp_TT;
}
```

I am not sure what is going wrong here
Thanks in advance

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477509/how-to-use-nsstring-drawinrect-to-center-text

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Thanks but my question is not to print within a frame the width will be static and height will be dynamic

Comment: And where do you put that text? Because it seems to me that you should use a UITableView and custom UITableViewCell qui three UILabel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Woah! Adding hardcoded blank spaces to get the desired UI would be a very bad way of doing it.
You should use [`NSAttributedStrings`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsattributedstring) to get the center-alignment.